# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows for trigger

Tags: oracle, ora-01422

I tried to insert new rows to check if my trigger works. But it returns the error in the title

Answer (score 1):

One big problem you have is that your joins are written improperly. I don't know what you're trying to do, but the part of your query which reads

```
INNER JOIN PURCHASE
  ON :NEW.SERVEDBY = P.EMPNO
```

will join *every row* from the `PURCHASE` table to the `P` subquery if :NEW.SERVEDBY happens to equal the value of EMPNO in any row returned by the `P` subquery. It may actually join every row from `PURCHASE` multiple times, if the conditions `:NEW.SERVEDBY = P.EMPNO` is matched multiple times. I suspect this isn't what you wanted, but since I don't know what your tables look like or what it is you're attempting to accomplish I can't suggest an approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Following query is returning more than one record.

```
SELECT DNAME INTO DeptName FROM (SELECT * FROM DEPT INNER JOIN EMP ON 
 DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO) P INNER JOIN PURCHASE ON :NEW.SERVEDBY = 
 P.EMPNO; 
-- use fetch first 1 row only or row_number analytical function or rownum pseudo column
```

You need to limit it to 1 record as `INTO` can take only one record.

Cheers!!